# v-for not updating input error from store vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, store, v-for

In store i have passengers array. This array will be updating by calling some actions. For example, when I typing secondName in input, I get id and value of this input.

This data uploading in vuex. But when I want to check error this is not working for me and I don't know why. I have problem with v-for, because error is not reactive.

```js
import CancelIcon from "@/components/icons/CancelIcon";
import ArrowDownIcon from "@/components/icons/ArrowDownIcon";
import MyDataButton from "@/components/MyDataButton";
import {mapState, mapActions, mapGetters} from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: "PassengersInfo",
  components: {MyDataButton, ArrowDownIcon, CancelIcon},
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
        'updateSecondName',
        'validateNameField',
        'getPassengersArrays'
    ])
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      passengers: state => state.passengers,
    }),
    ...mapGetters([
       'getPassengers',
        'getError'
    ]),
  },
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<nav>
        <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
          <button
              v-for="passenger in getPassengers"
              :key="passenger.id"
              :class="{active: passenger.id === 1}"
              class="nav-link"
              :id="'passenger-'+passenger.id+'-tab'"
              data-bs-toggle="tab"
              :data-bs-target="'#passenger-'+passenger.id"
              type="button" role="tab"
              :aria-controls="'passenger-'+passenger.id"
              :aria-selected="{true : passenger.id === 1}"
          >Пассажир №{{passenger.id}}</button>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="tab-content position-relative" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div
            v-for="passenger in getPassengers"
            :key="passenger.id"
            :class="{'show active': passenger.id === 1}"
            class="tab-pane fade"
            :id="'passenger-'+passenger.id"
            role="tabpanel"
            :aria-labelledby="'passenger-'+passenger.id+'-tab'">
          <div class="form-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="checkbox-form d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between w-100">
                  <MyDataButton class="d-none"/>
                  <div class="form-checks">
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" v-on:click="oneWay=true" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1" checked>
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">В одну сторону</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" v-on:click="oneWay=false"  name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Туда-обратно</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                    <button type="button" class="remove-button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#removeModal">
                      Убрать
                      <CancelIcon color="#1399FF"/>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <!--                        TODO сделать валидацию по классам .is-ok и .is-error-->
                <div class="col-3 col-lg-6 col-xl-3">
                  <label for="secondName" class="form-label">Фамилия</label>
                  <input
                      @input="updateSecondName($event);validateNameField($event);"
                      :value="passenger.secondName"
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control" :id="'secondName' + passenger.id"
                      placeholder="Иванов">
                  <!--                          TODO убрать d-none когда валидация неверная-->
                  {{passenger.error}}
                  <div v-if="passenger.error" class="error-feedback">{{passenger.error}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 col-lg-6 col-xl-3">
                  <label for="firstName" class="form-label">Имя</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Иван">
                  <!--                          TODO убрать d-none когда валидация неверная-->
                  <div class="error-feedback d-none">Укажите имя</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 col-lg-6 col-xl-3">
                  <label for="MiddleName" class="form-label">Отчество</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MiddleName" placeholder="Иванович">
                  <!--                          TODO убрать d-none когда валидация неверная-->
                  <div class="error-feedback d-none">Укажите отчество</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 col-lg-6 col-xl-3">
                  <label for="birthday" class="form-label">Дата рождения</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="birthday" placeholder="дд.мм.гггг">
                  <!--                          TODO убрать d-none когда валидация неверная-->
                  <div class="error-feedback d-none">Некорректная дата, вам больше 125 лет?</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row gy-2">
                <div class="col-3 col-lg-6 col-xl-3">
                  <label for="gender" class="form-label">Пол</label>
                  <select id="gender" class="form-select">
                    <option selected>Мужской</option>
                    <option>Женский</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 col-lg-6 col-xl-3">
                  <label for="citizenship" class="form-label">Гражданство</label>
                  <select id="citizenship" class="form-select">
                    <option selected>Российская Федерация</option>
                    <option>...</option>
                  </select>
                  <!--                          TODO убрать d-none когда валидация неверная-->
                  <div class="error-feedback d-none">Выберите пол</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 col-lg-6 col-xl-3">
                  <label for="document" class="form-label">Документ</label>
                  <select id="document" class="form-select">
                    <option selected>Паспорт РФ</option>
                    <option>...</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 col-lg-6 col-xl-3">
                  <label for="documentInfo" class="form-label">Серия и номер документа</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="documentInfo" placeholder="01 23 456789">
                  <!--                          TODO убрать d-none когда валидация неверная-->
                  <div class="error-feedback d-none">Некорректные серия и номер документа</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```js
export const passengerModule = {
    state: () => ({
        passengers: [],
        tripId: 0,
        flightId: 0,
        placeNumber: [],
        isLogin: false,
        buyerInfo: {
            firstName: '',
            secondName: '',
            email: '',
            number: '',
        },
        promocode: '',
    }),
    mutations: {
        addArraysPassengers(state, arraysPassengers) {
            state.passengers.push(...arraysPassengers)
        },
        updateSecondName(state, {value, id}) {
            // state.passengers[id-1] = {id: Number(id),secondName: value}
            state.passengers[id-1].secondName = value;
        },
        updateError(state, [error, id]) {
            state.passengers[id-1].error = error
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async getPassengersArrays(ctx) {
            const arraysPassengers = [ctx.getters.getPassengersArrays];
            await ctx.commit('addArraysPassengers', arraysPassengers)
        },
        updateSecondName(ctx, event) {
            const value = event.target.value;
            //исключить наименование и оставить только цифры в id при помощи replace
            const id = event.target.id.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");
            ctx.commit('updateSecondName', {value, id});
        },
        validateNameField(ctx, event) {
            const value = event.target.value;
            //получение названия поля
            const field = event.target.id.replace(/[0-9]/g, '')
            //исключить наименование и оставить только цифры в id при помощи replace
            const id = event.target.id.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");
            if (field === 'secondName' && value === '') {
                ctx.commit('updateError', ['заполните фамилию', id]);
            }
            if (field === 'secondName' && value !== '') {
                ctx.commit('updateError', ['', id])
            }
        }
    },
    getters: {
        getPassengers(state, getters) {
            return state.passengers;
        },
        getPassengersArrays(state, getters) {
            return {id: getters.adults+getters.childrens}
        }
    },
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: I thought the v-for only updated if the key changed?

Comment: i'am trying to figure out this topic

Comment: the key updating is NOT required for v-for to rerun.  anyways, `passenger.error` should be reactive so there must be an error somewhere breaking your reactivity.  any error messages in your dev console?  this will be hard to diagnose without a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  please provide one if you can!